# Opposite of append in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `.append` to add to a div

```
$(this).append('<ul><li>test</li></ul>');
```

how can I search for a `<ul>` and remove it if it exists in the children of `$(this)`?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You could use `remove()`. More information on [jQuery remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
$(this).children("ul").remove();
```

Note that this will remove *all* `ul` elements that are children.

Comment: I want to fetch an element(div) to a variable. how can i do this?

Answer (score 27):

The opposite of `.append()` is `.prepend()`.

From the [jQuery documentation for prepend…](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

> The .prepend() method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the last child, use .append()).

*I realize this doesn’t answer the OP’s **specific** case. But it does answer the **question heading.** :) And it’s the first hit on Google for “jquery opposite append”.*

Comment: Answers my question. "What's the opposite of append"

Answer (score 18):

Use the [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method:

```
$(this).children("ul").remove();
```

Answer (score 14):

What you also should consider, is keeping a reference to the created element, then you can easily remove it specificly:

```
   var newUL = $('<ul><li>test</li></ul>');
   $(this).append(newUL);

   // Later ...

   newUL.remove();
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed What don't you understand?

Answer (score 10):

just had the same problem and ive come across this - which actually does the trick for me:

```
// $("#the_div").contents().remove();
// or short: 
$("#the_div").empty();
$("#the_div").append("HTML goes in here...");
```

Comment: I believe `.contents().remove()` equals `.empty()`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether you know of chaining - just in case yo don't, you can combine statements in jQuery like `$(...).empty().append(...)` :)

Answer (score 5):

Opposite up is `children()`, but opposite in position is `prepend()`.

[Here](https://www.elated.com/jquery-adding-elements/) a very good tutorial.