# What is the opposite of append in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `$('.posts').append('test')` to add 'test' as the last element in the posts `div`. How can I make it the first element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opposite of append in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934488/opposite-of-append-in-jquery)

Comment: you can use **prepend** instead of **append**

Comment: @Tom: You should read the question more carefully ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript: how to append div in "begining" of another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110484/javascript-how-to-append-div-in-begining-of-another-div)

Comment: @FelixKling Ah good point! More coffee is needed!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use with `.prepend()` like

```
$('.posts').prepend('test');
```

Try this [**LINK**](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Answer (score 4):

You use  `prepend()`

```
('.posts').prepend('test');
```